# Android Studio was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005)

Tags: android-studio

[image: 1]
**Problem**
Recently I downloaded android studio for some projects. After installing when I tried to run the program it says ( Android studio was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005).

**What I tried**

- I tried reinstalling the program and restarted my pc still it didnt worked out.
- I again tried to installing from zip file rather then .exe but still it shows same things.
- I tried to reinstalling and hoping it will work. But it didnt went well.

How do i fix this problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error too (Windows 11 Pro, 64 Bit). I solved the problem by adjusting the **App&Browser Control** >>> **Exploit Protection** settings by **turning off** all of controls.

[image: Windows 11 Exploit Protection]